# crystal report 8.5 filter records

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to this position (production support) and asked to look into a problem in a crystal report 8.5. I am new to crystal report as well with some basic training only.

The report seems to be missing some records. It uses a SQL Server 2005 procedure as data source. I tested with same parameters the report used on the procedure and the it returns all records including the missing records in the report. So I think the report must filter the records. Then I checked Record Selection Formula, I saw something in there but it seems not related to the missing records. For testing, I commented them all, run the report but the records are still missing.

So I guess there may be something else that filters the data?

Comment: Other things to check: conditional suppression of sections / fields; also **group** selection formula (different to record selection formula).

Comment: I have checked all these actually. Strangely, when I add a condition in the Record Selection Formula to explicitly show the missing record (e.g. item_no = 'xx') then the report show just that record.

Comment: Are you sure the details section isn't suppressed (conditionally or otherwise)? That makes it sound as though records are being displayed in group sections (headings or footings); without a special selection formula, the "missing" ones aren't the first (group header) or last (group footer) in the group, so don't get displayed, but **are** both first and last in the group when the record selection formula explicitly selects only that record.

Comment: All right, it's something in top N group expert. The report only lists top 50 items for a group based on sales units. Anyway, thanks. I know it's something hard to describe here.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be something in top N group expert. The report only lists top 50 items for a group based on sales units.

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from exporting the report definition into a .txt file by clicking file > export > export report > report definition txt ( you have to scroll for it).  I believe this functionality existed back in 8.5.

What it does is display the underlying formatting, filtering and formulas in an easy to read format.  You should be able to pick out what is happening much more quickly than clicking through all the potential places for something to be hidden.  I see that you answered your own question but seeing that you're new to this position this is a troubleshooting tip I found invaluable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But there is no export under File menu in 8.5.